# The Nature of the Hadith in Ash Shifa

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, authenticity

There is a Hadith in Page 48 of Ash Shifa which speaks of the musk of the Prophet. I can’t find the Arabic but I will like to know the authenticity of the report and it’s legitimacy if it can be explained.

> Al-Muzani and al-Harbi related that Jabir said, “The Prophet, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, let me ride behind him, so I put my mouth on the seal of prophethood and it spread over me like musk.
> [وروى المزني والحربي عن جابر أردفني النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم خلفه فالتقمت خاتم النبوة بفمي فكان ينم على مسكا](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1753/72)

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].